# SQLで重なる二つの期間がある場合に、一つにつなげた期間を求める方法

Tags: sql

お世話になります。

SQL(MicrosoftAccess)で、異なる二つの期間のレコードがある場合、一つにつなげた
期間として結果を求める書き方を教えてください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

実用的かは知りませんが以下の要領で実現できると思います。

まず`start`と`end`を1つの列にまとめ、区別のために`1`と`-1`の符号を振ります。

```
SELECT 1 Type, start Date from table
UNION ALL
SELECT -1, end from table
```

結果

```
 1 2013-03-01
 1 2013-05-01
 1 2013-06-01
-1 2013-07-10
-1 2013-07-31
-1 2013-08-30
 1 2013-09-15
 1 2013-10-01
-1 2013-11-30
-1 2013-12-31
```

次にこの結果セットをType,Dateの昇順に並べてTypeの和を求めます。

```
SELECT a.Type, a.Date
     , (SELECT SUM(b.Type)
          FROM set1 b
         WHERE b.Date < a.Date
            OR (b.Date = a.Date AND b.Type <= a.Type)) RunningTotal
FROM set1 a
```

結果

```
 1 2013-03-01 1
 1 2013-05-01 2
 1 2013-06-01 3
-1 2013-07-10 2
-1 2013-07-31 1
-1 2013-08-30 0
 1 2013-09-15 1
 1 2013-10-01 2
-1 2013-11-30 1
-1 2013-12-31 0
```

この数字は該当日付から次の日付までの区間で何個のレコードが重なっているかを表しています。求めたいのは1個以上のレコードが存在する区間ですので`0→1`と`1→0`の変動を抽出すればよく、つまり`(Type, RunningTotal)`が`(1, 1)`～`(-1, 0)`の間を探せばよいです。

```
SELECT a.Date Start
     , (SELECT MIN(b.Date)
          FROM set2 b
         WHERE Type = -1
           AND RunningTotal = 0
           AND b.Date > a.Date) End
  FROM set2 a
 WHERE Type = 1 AND RunningTotal = 1
```

Comment: お礼が遅れて申し訳ありません。いつもありがとうございます。頂いた方法で処理できましたが、実行速度が重いような気がします。約55000件のレコードを処理していますが、7,8分の時間がかかってしまうのですが、これは致し方ないのでしょうか。

Comment: 速度が問題になるのでしたらクエリー自体は最初の`UNION ALL`に`ORDER`を追加したものを使い、プログラムで`RunningTotal`を計算していった方が良いですよ。高級なRDBMSであれば分析関数を用いた高速なクエリーもできると思いますが、Accessでは無理ですね。